# Spacing in Equation

Tags: amsmath

> 1. The spacing is not nice... any better way to improve...
> 2. Is it possible to increase the space above and below divider line...

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2.5in, paperheight=2.5in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\Dfrac}[2]{%
  \dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}%
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \dfrac{
\dfrac{1}{\cos \theta}\left[\sin \theta - \cos \theta + 1 \right]
}{
\dfrac{1}{\cos \theta}\left[\sin \theta + \cos \theta - 1 \right]
}\\
%
&= \Dfrac{
\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} - \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta} + \dfrac{1}{\cos \theta} 
}{
\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} + \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta} - \dfrac{1}{\cos \theta}
}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use those `\dfrac` and `\displaystyle` stuff?

Comment: Well don't expect decent spacing if you kill the size choices and stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose this workaround, using `\cfrac` in the denominator and for the numerator, adding a `\bigstrut[b]` or a phantom letter with descender in the relevant places:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2.5in, paperheight=2.5in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\Dfrac}[2]{%
  \dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}%
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \dfrac{
\dfrac{1}{\cos θ\bigstrut[b]}\left[\sin θ- \cos θ+ 1 \right]
}{
\cfrac{1}{\cos θ}\left[\sin θ+ \cos θ- 1 \right]
}\\[1ex]
&= \Dfrac{
\frac{\sin θ}{\cos θ\vphantom{g}} - \frac{\cos θ}{\cos θ} + \frac{1}{\cos θ}
}{
\frac{\sin θ}{\cos θ} + \frac{\cos θ}{\cos θ} - \cfrac{1}{\cos θ}
}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Insert some `\mathstrut` objects, space out the two rows and don't use `\left` and `\right` when unnecessary (like in this case).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}

\newcommand{\ms}{\mathstrut} % shorthand
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \frac{
  \dfrac{1}{\ms\cos \theta}[\sin \theta - \cos \theta + 1]
}{
  \dfrac{\ms 1}{\cos \theta}[\sin \theta + \cos \theta - 1]
}
\\[2ex]
&= \frac{
  \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\ms\cos \theta} -
  \dfrac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta} +
  \dfrac{1}{\cos \theta} 
}{
  \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} +
  \dfrac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta} -
  \dfrac{\ms 1}{\cos \theta}
}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]